# Tkinter ~ Is Drawing a Canvas to GUI possible using .grid()?

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

Is it possible to draw lines such as the following with the Tkinter `.grid()` system? Every tutorial that talks about `canvas` drawing uses `.pack()` exclusively.

There are no answers for using `canvas` with `.grid()` when you search online.

I have tried using canvas with `.grid()` but my GUI got completely messed up and no lines were drawn.

Is it actually possible to use canvas with `.grid()`?

Comment: _"There are no answers for using canvas with .grid() when you search online"_ - At the time that I write this there are [144 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btkinter%5D+canvas.grid+is%3Aanswer) on this site alone which contain the string `canvas.grid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use neither `grid` nor `pack` for drawing items on a canvas. The canvas has the following methods for drawing:

- create_arc
- create_bitmap
- create_image
- create_line
- create_oval
- create_polygon
- create_rectangle
- create_text
- create_window

If you're not actually asking about drawing figures on canvas, but on adding the canvas to a window with `pack` or `grid`, you can use either.